# Random mixed-up

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

So in my carousel I implemented this:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{   
   // int randomforIndex = arc4random()%[images count]+1;
        UIImageView *imageView  = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:index]]];
        return imageView;


}
```

I assign my images with `NSString`. That whenever a carousel with an image stops at a specific `[images objectAtIndex:index]` it will do a corresponding action.
But when I use the `randomforIndex` part for my `index` it all get mixed-up. So my problem is how am I going to random the images without randoming their values.

This is how I add my images with NSString:

```
for (int x=1; x<76;x++) {
        // add as NSString
        [images addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", x]];
            }
```

Comment: "It all gets mixed up".  With random numbers, that sounds like the goal...What exactly is happening?

Comment: yes, images in my array are by numbers so : 1.png,2.png...... my goal is to shuffle them. So I tried the random. But when I use random the NSString assign to it also get mixed-up. Like when iCarousel stops at 2.png it shows action 5.

Comment: just shuffle the "images" array

Comment: how to shuffle the "images" array? Its in my awake from nib.

Comment: @dexter: in my answer below you have two links to shuffle-categories for NSArray.

Comment: Is it okay for NSMutableArray?

Comment: Yes - for shuffling NSMutableArray is actually a must. The linked categories use it internally but you can easily modify this categories to NSMutableArray (make it a category of NSMutableArray instead of NSArray). Or you could possibly use the category as-is and typecast your NSMutableArray as (NSArray *) when using this category.

Comment: Having errors with the shuffle.

Comment: What kind of errors? Which one of the provided links are you trying to use? http://www.cocoanetics.com/2009/04/shuffling-an-nsarray/ also has an example how to use it.

Comment: Issues with NSMutableArray says on mine.

Comment: I edited my answer and tested the code - it definetly works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this: first you fill up you `images` array using your code. Then you **shuffle** this ordered array. There's a nice NSArray shuffle category here: [Shuffling an NSArray](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2009/04/shuffling-an-nsarray/).

Note that you should delete the empty #import line in `NSArray+Helpers.h`

```
images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int x=1; x<76;x++)
{
    [images addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", x]];
}
images = (NSMutableArray *)[images shuffled];
```

This part of code is tested and it works.

From this point on you should be fine using simple viewForItemAtIndex without any randomizations, since filenames are already shuffeld.

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{   
    if (view == nil)
    {
        view = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    }

    UIImage* nimage = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:index]];
    view.image = nimage;
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,nimage.size.width,nimage.size.height);  

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Of course, you're right. Thanks for reminder and for downvote.

Comment: plz reuse the "reusingView" , then if there NO ARC,  autorelease the new UIImageView

Comment: so Im going to make another class for the NSArray+helpers for my project?

Comment: Error, with the `self count` part.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to store the random list separately.  Make another array and put the random sequence into that one.  You can then use that one as your data source and keep the link between number and image intact.

Comment: Nope, that's just the thought that came to my head.  It's not that much different then what you are doing now.  Instead of taking the random number in `viewForItemAtIndex`, calculate all the random numbers first and put them into another array.  Then use *that* array in the `viewForItemAtIndex` method.